# Can I still authorize requests with the YouTube v3 API without using OAuth?

Tags: authorization, youtube-api

*[Google recommended I ask questions about their API here.](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html)*

I've been testing out v3 of the YouTube API. Sometime this week, it appears have made a yet-to-documented behavior change. Before, I could just put "key=$foo" in my URLs to authenticate them, which is all I need for my simple server-side use. The documentation included example URLs using this Authorization method, like this one:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3alpha/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=API_KEY&part=id,snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status

(*from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)*.)

Now when I try this method, instead of getting back a successful response, I get this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

If the currently documented syntax isn't going to work anymore, what's the next-based simple authorization option to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `key=API_KEY URL` parameter should still work for v3 in general, whenever you're making an unauthenticated request.

The engineering team is in the middle of pushing out some breaking changes to the backend services, though, and they broke this functionality in the meantime. I'd expect it to be fixed sometime soon—it's difficult to do anything using v3 at the moment.